# What form is it "understand someone to have Verb+ed? Is it a right form?

Tags: grammar

As in "his answer does not even attempt to teach any skills, which I understand the OP to have requested"

Could someone tell me what form of use this is and share a reference link?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is a construction in literary and formal English, a pattern borrowed from Latin, where it is referred to as "[accusative and infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_and_infinitive)". I don't know any other name for it in English.

Not many people would use it in ordinary conversation.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a resource to this, interesting, why it doesn't say instead "understand that OP has requested"? In the link it says this "someone to have done" is Latin, but I haven't heard this old form being still used today. Is it commonly used in spoken or written language?

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu: as I said, it is not common in spoken English, but you will certainly find it in more formal written English. The iWeb corpus has 1115 instances of "understand PRONOUN to VERB" but Hansard (British Parliament) has 1970 instances, IN speech "understand that PRONOUN VERB" is much more common.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great, detailed answer